# How to create an `Instances` in Weka from a `List<Instance>`?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, instances

I am using Weka as a part of a much longer pipeline, and as a result, I can't afford to write all the data to a file or database just to create an `Instances` object. What I can do on-the-fly is to create a list of `Instance` objects.

From [this page of their API](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html) I can see that `Instances` implements `List<Instance>`, but Weka doesn't seem to have a public constructor that will take a `List<Instance>` as argument. I tried a crude casting as well:

```
List<Instance> instanceList;
while ( ... ) {         // some conditional loop
    Instance inst = ... // more code where I am populating an individual instance
    instanceList.add(inst);
}
Instances instances = (Instances) instanceList;
```

In the last line above, Idea Intellij shows me a warning that I may run into a `ClassCastException`. How can I safely create `Instances` from my individual `Instance` objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create one using this [constructor](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#Instances%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList,%20int%29), and then add them one by one to the new Instances object.

Or switch to not Weka.

Comment: I tried using that constructor, but it ends up doing not-what-I-want. It's a fairly detailed issue, so I put that up as a [separate question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768607/using-stringtowordvector-in-weka-with-internal-data-structures)

Comment: What do you mean "not-what-you-want?" It creates an empty Instances list which is what you need, then you add them to it. Thats exactly what the question you wrote asked!

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment, it's a fairly detailed issue. What I mean by "not-what-I-want" is an entire question by itself (to which I have linked).

Comment: My apologies for the first comment. It turns out that I was making a mistake while creating the attributes, which is why the dataset (i.e. the `Instances` object) was different from what I had expected.