# Using StringToWordVector in Weka with internal data structures

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, weka

I am trying to obtain document clustering using Weka. The process is a part of a larger pipeline, and I really can't afford to write out arff files. I have all the documents and the bag of words in each document as a `Map<String, Multiset<String>>` structure, where the keys are document names, and the `Multiset<String>` values are the *bags* of words in the documents. I have two questions, really:

**(1) Current approach ends up clustering terms, not documents:**

```
public final Instances buildDocumentInstances(TreeMap<String, Multiset<String>> docToTermsMap, String encoding) throws IOException {
    int dimension = TermToDocumentFrequencyMap.navigableKeySet().size();
    FastVector attributes = new FastVector(dimension);
    for (String s : TermToDocumentFrequencyMap.navigableKeySet()) attributes.addElement(new Attribute(s));
    List<Instance> instances = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Multiset<String>> entry : docToTermsMap.entrySet()) {
        Instance instance = new Instance(dimension);
        for (Multiset.Entry<String> ms_entry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            Integer index = TermToIndexMap.get(ms_entry.getElement());
            if (index != null)
                switch (encoding) {
                case "tf":
                    instance.setValue(index, ms_entry.getCount());
                    break;
                case "binary":
                    instance.setValue(index, ms_entry.getCount() > 0 ? 1 : 0);
                    break;
                case "tfidf":
                    double tf = ms_entry.getCount();
                    double df = TermToDocumentFrequencyMap.get(ms_entry.getElement());
                    double idf = Math.log(TermToIndexMap.size() / df);
                    instance.setValue(index, tf * idf);
                    break;
                }
        }
        instances.add(instance);
    }
    Instances dataset = new Instances("My Dataset Name", attributes, instances.size());
    for (Instance instance : instances) dataset.add(instance);
    return dataset;
}
```

I am trying to create individual `Instance` objects, and then create a dataset by adding them to an `Instances` object. Each instance is a document-vector (with 0/1, tf or tf-idf encoding). Also, each word is a separate attribute. But when I run `SimpleKMeans#buildClusterer`, the output shows that it's clustering the words, not the documents. I am clearly doing something horribly wrong, but I can't figure out what that mistake is.

**(2) How to use StringToWordVector in this scenario?**
Everywhere I have looked, people suggest using `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector` to cluster documents. But, I can't find any examples where I can use it in a way that allows me take the words from my *document --> bag-of-words* structure. [Note: In my case, it is a `Map<String, Multiset<String>`, but that is not a rigid requirement. I can transform it into some other data structure if `StringToWordVector` requires it.]

Comment: If you can't afford to write out your data to  `.arff` files, don't use Weka. You then also won't be able to afford using Weka...

Comment: It turns out that the first part of my question is irrelevant: I was misinterpreting the cluster output. I'm now able to use Weka without any .arff files. It just surprises me that a class like `StringToWordVector` is so inflexible and rather opaque (I tried understanding the source code, but it's not easy to get a clear picture of exactly what's going on).

Much of NLP relies on processes like POS tagging, PCFG parse trees, etc. The current design of Weka kind of forces all this sort of work to resort to other tools. That's a shame, really, because they have built an excellent resource!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using multiple tools. I always do the preprocessing separate from the analysis, to get a more flexible process.

Comment: Couldn't agree more ... hence the upvote :-)